# VB Registry Edit

Tags: vb.net, registry

I tried edit registry using VB.net . I watched one YouTube tut.However I tried to do something and it didn't work at all :

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim Registry As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser
            Dim Key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Registry.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
            MsgBox(Key.GetValue("AmIcoSinglun64").ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

[image]

Unfortunately I got error : Null Pointer Exception

Comment: oh sorry i press enter before finish creating

Comment: Are you using the x86 as platform target?

Comment: well im targeting the paths of programs that run on win start (im with win 64 bit sys)

Comment: That's not what he asked.  Project + Properties, Compile tab, Target CPU setting.  Untick Prefer 32-bit.  If you have an older version of VS then click the Advanced Compile Options button to find that setting.

Comment: I'd guess the problem is regedit redirection, but i never saw that within CurrentUser keys, but check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485211/vb-net-2010-reading-from-registry-doesnt-work-win-7)

Comment: i cant get Target CPU setting i tried by enableing Tools>Options>Projects and Solutions>Gneral>Show advanced build configorations ,but i still dont get Build tab on Properties (VB2010)

Answer (score 0):

Use this for saving a value

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.SetValue("MyName", "MyValue")
```

Us this for getting a value

```
Dim RegistryCheck As String = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue("Study")
```